# NextJS API route without the "api" part of the url?

Tags: next.js

I can have a API route in NextJS 13. This endpoint is accessible at http://localhost:8080/api/foo/bar

```
// pages/api/foo/bar.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  res.status(200).json({ foo: "bar2" });
}
```

However I dont want to have "api" as part of the url eg http://localhost:8080/foo/bar

If don't have 'api' as one of the folders eg: pages/foo/bar.ts then for the URL above I get an error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Im assuming that its erroring as its expecting the default export to be a React component, but im not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Without `/api`, there is no way Next.js knows it's an API route, and hence it treats it as React component. I'm afraid there is no workaround: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you have to use `/api` route if you use Nextjs API.
So you can create a custom server and redirect route `/foo` to `/api/foo`

An example:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname } = parsedUrl;


    if (pathname === '/foo') {
      return app.render(req, res, '/api/foo', parsedUrl.query);
    }


    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  });

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:4000');
  });
});
```